# How do I read the definition of ex_intro?

Tags: coq

I'm reading [Mike Nahas's introductory Coq tutorial](https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial-nahas), which says:

> The arguments to "ex_intro" are:
>
> - the predicate
> - the witness
> - a proof of the predicated called with the witness

I looked at [the definition](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html):

```
Inductive ex (A:Type) (P:A -> Prop) : Prop :=
  ex_intro : forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=A) P.
```

and I'm having trouble parsing it. Which parts of the expression `forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=A) P` correspond to those three arguments (predicate, witness, and proof)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To understand what Mike meant, it's better to launch the Coq interpreter and query for the type of `ex_intro`:

```
Check ex_intro.
```

You should then see:

```
ex_intro
     : forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop) (x : A), P x -> exists x, P x
```

This says that `ex_intro` takes not only 3, but 4 arguments:

- the type of the thing you're quantifying over, `A`;
- the predicate `P : A -> Prop`;
- the witness `x : A`; and
- a proof of `P x`, asserting that `x` is a valid witness.

If you combine all of those things, you get a proof of `exists x : A, P x`. For example, `@ex_intro nat (fun n => n = 3) 3 eq_refl` is a proof of `exists n, n = 3`.

Thus, the difference between the actual type of `ex_intro` and the one you read on the definition is that the former includes all of the parameters that are given in the header -- in this case, `A` and `P`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, those inductive type definitions can be difficult to read.

The first part is:

```
Inductive ex (A:Type) (P:A -> Prop) : Prop :=
```

This is what is associated with the type itself.   So any time you see an `ex`,  it will have an `A` and and a `P` and the `ex` will be of type `Prop`.  Skipping `A` for the moment, let's focus on `P` which is the predicate.  So, if we use as our example "there exists a natural number which is prime", `P` might be `is_prime`, where `is_prime` takes a `nat` (natural number) as an argument and there can exist a proof of it if the `nat` is prime.

In this example, `A` would be `nat`. In the tutorial, `A` isn't mentioned because Coq can always infer it.  Given the predicate, Coq can get the type of `A` by looking at the type of the predicate's argument.

To summarize up to here, in our example, the type would be `ex nat is_prime`.  This says there exists a nat that is prime, but it does not say which nat.  When we construct an `ex nat is_prime`, we will need to say which one - we will need a "witness".  And that leads us to the constructor definition:

```
ex_intro : forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=A) P.
```

The constructor is named `ex_intro`.  What's tricky here is that the constructor has all the parameters for the type.  So, before we get to the ones listed after `ex_intro`, we have to include the ones for the type: `A` and `P`.

After those parameters come the ones listed after `ex_intro`: `x`, which is the witness, and `P x`, which is a proof that the predicate holds for the witness.  Using our example, `x` might be 2 and `P x` would be a proof of `(is_prime 2)`.

The constructor needs to specify the parameters for the type `ex` that it is constructing.  That is what's happening after the arrow (`->`).  These do not have to match the parameters used in calling the constructor, but they usually do.  To accomplish that, the argument `A` is *not* being inferred - it is being passed explicitly.  The `(A:=A)` says that the parameter `A` in `ex` should be equal to the `A` in the call to the constructor.  Likewise, the parameters `P` of `ex` is being set to `P` from the call to the constructor.

So, if we had `proof_that_2_is_prime` with type `(prime 2)`, we can call `ex_intro is_prime 2 proof_that_2_is_prime` and it would have type `ex nat is_prime`.  Which is our proof that there exists a natural number that is prime.

---

To answer your question directly: In the expression `forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=A)`, `x:A` is the witness and `P x` is the proof that the witness is true.  The expression does not contain the predicate, because that is part of the type's parameters which must be passed to the constructor `ex_intro`.  The tutorial's list of parameters does not include `A`, because is inferred by Coq.

I hope you understand why I thought this discussion was too detailed for my tutorial!  Thanks for the question.

Comment: Thanks for having taken the time to write such a detailed answer. But I think the paragraph about what is after the arrow is wrong. Indeed, `A` and `P` are parameters of the type and therefore you do not have the choice in the constructors. You cannot for example write `ex_intro : forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=nat) P`. And by the way, you can omit `(A:=A)`. This is different from the definition `Inductive ex : forall A, (A -> Prop) ->Prop`, where you would have more freedom in the way you define the constructors.