# Relationship between existential and universal quantifier in an inductive Coq definition

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

Suppose I want an inductive definiton of a substring (with string being just a synonym for list).

```
Inductive substring {A : Set} (w : string A) :
                    (string A) -> Prop :=
  | SS_substr : forall x y z : string A,
                  x ++ y ++ z = w ->
                  substring w y.
```

Here I can for example prove the following:

```
Theorem test : substring [3;4;1] [4].
Proof.
  eapply SS_substr.
  cbn.
  instantiate (1:=[1]).
  instantiate (1:=[3]).
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

However, the proof is "existential" rather than "universal", in spite of the fact that the inductive definition states `forall x y z` and only then constrains their shapes. This seems somewhat unintuitive to me. What gives?

Also, is it possible to make an inductive definition using `exists x : string A, exists y : string A, exists z : string, x ++ y ++ z = w -> substring w y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to note is that `exists` is not a built-in functionality of Coq (contrary to `forall`). Actually, `exists` itself is a notation, but behind there is an inductive type named `ex`. The notation and the inductive type are defined in the [Coq standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html#ex). Here is the definition of `ex`:

```
Inductive ex (A:Type) (P:A -> Prop) : Prop :=
    ex_intro : forall x:A, P x -> ex (A:=A) P.
```

It is defined using one constructor and a universal quantification, like your `substring` type, so it is not surprising that your `susbtring` type seems to be "existential" at some point.

Of course, you can define your type using `exists`, and you do not even need `Inductive`.

```
Definition substring' {A : Set} (w y : string A) : Prop :=
    exists x z, x ++ y ++ z = w.
```

Comment: Neat, thanks! (Jibadiba podajiba brm brm brm - needed more characters)

Comment: @AntlerM Even if I answered your initial question, you should wait before selecting my post as the solution, as it could discourage other users to post something interesting about the subject.

Comment: Well, for my purposes, it makes sense that existential certainly follows from universal (surely if forall x in A, P x then exists x' : A, P x' assuming A is not empty) which explains just about everything I was wondering about; that said, as others may stumble upon this at some point, leaving room for more "interestings" on the subject sounds reasonable. Sadly I can't upboat you with 13 rep :).

Comment: @AntlerM I might be wrong, but I think you're misreading the definition of `ex_intro`. `ex_intro` is a *dependently*-typed function (constructor), that takes 4 arguments: a type `A`, a predicate `P : A -> Prop`, an `x` of type `A` **and** a proof of `P x` (in this last part dependent types play crucial role!), then it sort of wraps them together in one bundle which is `exists`. There is nothing that requires you to prove `forall x, P x`! And eponier has just showed that with dependent types one doesn't need `exists` as a separate (independent) entity -- it can be encoded within the system.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thanks for making things clear as usual. I realized in your comment that the fact that `exists` is not built-in is not obvious. I edited my post to make things clearer.

Comment: @eponier I like your edit! Especially one thing is pretty convenient -- the precise link to `ex`. How did you do it? I understand that I can append `#ex` to `Coq.Init.Logic.html`. But is there a way to link to, say, `Notation "x = y" := (x = y :>_) : type_scope.` (in that same html doc)?

Comment: @AntonTrunov I must admit I looked into the html source code. But there is a simpler way to do it: find a use of the object you want to refer to, since the documentation usually links to the definition of the object. For instance, `=` is used in `eq_sym` just after the definition. If you click on the `=`, you are sent to the definition. Just copy the url then. For this example, the link is https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html#1c39bf18749e5cc609e83c0a0ba5a372.

Comment: Nice and simple! Thank you.

Comment: @AntonTrunov right - so the `forall x` is in this scenario simply states that "given any arbitrary element `x`"... (and a proof that `P` holds for that element `x`), I give you a bundle (an ordered pair, in some sense), with the first element being that element `x` and the second its proof that `P x`. Forall = for arbitrary, that is, right?

Comment: @AntlerM Yes, it's kind of arbitrary in the sense that *any* `x` for which `P x` is provable would do, so it doesn't matter exactly which `x` and which proof of `P x` you provide. An important thing here is you've got to provide *both*. You can't get a value of type `ex` for a completely arbitrary `x` unless `forall x, P x`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Ooo that's a good observation. So, in some sense, you can't get a curried version of it! :) This is quite interesting - how existential quantification is really somewhat less fundamental than the universal one. (It makes sense un-intuitively, considering you can build everything off of implication / forall in coq, but intuitively it's (at least to me) not as clear.)

Comment: @AntlerM You can partially apply `ex_intro`. E.g. the type of `ex_intro (fun n => n = 0) 0` is `0 = 0 -> exists n : nat, n = 0`. It's a partially applied constructor, which "waits" for a proof of `0 = 0`. You might also want to look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777736/how-do-i-read-the-definition-of-ex-intro).